# How to account for lag in a simple regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, lags

I'm trying to do a regression with data over time, and where I suspect there may be a lag component in the relationship between my dependent and independent variables.  I've actually found some data online [here](http://arungaikwad.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/predicting-marketing-campaign-with-r/) that provides a good minimal example

```
sales<-data.frame(Quarter=1:8, Sales=c(16850, 12010, 14740, 13890, 12950, 15640, 14960, 13630), Newspaper=c(1000, 500, 2000, 1000, 1000, 500, 1000, 500), TV=c(500, 500, 500, 1000, 500, 1000, 1000, 1500), Online=c(1500, 500, 500, 1000, 500, 1000, 1000, 500))
lm(data=sales, Sales~Newspaper+TV+Online)
```

So the data I found is sales figures per quarter and matching advertising expenditure, but I would expect there to be a lag between advertising and purchases.  How can I model that in this data ?

Answer (score 7):

I would have a look to the R package dynlm. It provides an L operator that makes you model lag  term in the regression equation. The examples in the dynlm function should give you tips to work around on your problem. Pay attention to configure the time series structure.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the chapter on dynamic models in [Market Response Models: Econometric and Time Series Analysis](http://books.google.com/books/about/Market_Response_Models.html?id=xZyJamKdpIsC) helpful. It's not R-specific in any way, but it will walk you through the basic model with lags and leads (when customers and/or competitors anticipate a marketing action and adjust their behavior before that action takes place).