# Incorporate a lag effect into a linear mixed regression model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, repeated-measures, predictor, lags

**My data**:

I have 80 years of repeated measures data (forest growth rates) that unfortunately were not sampled regularly. My understanding is that this **precludes me from using time series analyses** (at least in any straightforward way that doesn't require more data than I have).

I have `GrowthRate`, forest `Age`, and `Biomass.lost` as known variables (for 30 `Plots`).

**My question**:

I can model the effects of `Biomass.lost` on `GrowthRate` trends across age via:  `GR ~ Age + BL`.

But what if I think `Biomass.lost` plays a larger role as a *lagged* effect?

Specifically, I think that perhaps that `GrowthRate` increases in sampling periods *after* the period of recorded `biomass lost`.

**How do I incorporate this *lagged* effect of my predictor  into a mixed model?**

Is it as easy as shifting my real `Biomass.lost` values in the dataset by a single sampling year?

- for example, reassigning `Biomass.lost` in Plot 4 in sampling year 1 to sampling year 2

This doesn't seem at all like an appropriate approach, but I'm not sure...

<sup>(I'm using the `lmer` package in `R`, btw, if you wouldn't mind framing your answer in the context of that program)</sup>

Comment: I know questions about lags in regression have been asked before (e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/24837/80624) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/165255/80624)), but they have always bee in the context of time series analyses.

Comment: Yes, it's as straightforward as you guessed. However, if your samples were not collected regularly, calculating a consistent lag (say 1 year) might be difficult, leaving you with lots of missing values.

Comment: You could have a look at the tag [tag:unevenly-spaced-time-series]